# Python: A function to check the last string

Tags: python, python-3.x

the function takes user's input (a string). It should return **True** if the last character appears more than once in the string, regardless if it's upper or lower case, otherwise it returns **False**.
What is wrong with the code?

```
def last_early(word):
    word.lower()
    if word.count(word[-1]) > 1:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

This is what I expect:

```
>>> last_early("happy birthday")
True
>>> last_early("best of luck")
False
>>> last_early("Wow")
True
>>> last_early("X")
False
```

Comment: The line `word.lower()` has no effect. String methods return **new** string objects as strings are **immutabe**. You probably want `word = word.lower()`

Comment: No need to count:  `return word[-1].lower() in word[:-1].lower()`.  If the last letter is present elsewhere in the word, then you have more than one of it.

Answer (score 0):

- Try:

```py
def last_early(word):
    lower_word = word.lower() # word.lower won't change word itself
    if lower_word.count(lower_word[-1]) > 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

- you can test by running:

```py
def testLastEarly():
    print("testing last_early()...",end="")
    assert(last_early("happy birthday") == True)
    assert(last_early("best of luck") == False)
    assert(last_early("Wow") == True)
    assert(last_early("X") == False)
    print("pass")

testLastEarly()
```

- if you want to try more exercise, check out [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~112/notes/hw1.html)